# Nodejs persist a sqlite in-memory database

Tags: node.js, sqlite, persist, in-memory

I'm using the nodejs sqlite library (https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3). How can i persist an in-memory database to disk? Since in the c/c++ implementation there are the backup api how can i persist in nodejs with this library? (or with another library/mechanism)

Comment: Why are you using an in-memory database when you do not want to have it in memory?

Comment: I want to have an-in memory database for performance reasons and i want to save it (in a check point) every x minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2016, [using the backup API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1437327/11654) was the only way.
And Node.js did not implement this API. But now, see Jared's answer.

Anyway, just use a normal, on-disk database.
You can make it as unsafe as an in-memory database with [PRAGMA synchronous = OFF](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) now supports the backup api (see [this test file](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/blob/593c9d498be2510d286349134537e3bf89401c4a/test/backup.test.js)). Unfortunately, the [API Documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API) hasn't been updated since 2017, so it's easy to miss.

It looks like the simplest way to do it would be:

```js
        var backup = db.backup('test/tmp/backup.db');
        backup.step(-1, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            backup.finish(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                // It finished!
            });
        });
```

### Note: I'd recommend [better-sqlite3](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3) these days

And better-sqlite3 has [documentation for its backup api](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/api.md#backupdestination-options---promise)!

As simple as

```js
db.backup(`my-backup.db`)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('backup complete!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('backup failed:', err);
  });
```