# Periodically append new rows from in memory database to disk in SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have an in memory database in SQLite written in c++. Data is being inserted into the in-memory datbase at a very fast rate. I want to persist the database to disk for recovery purposes but I want to do it periodically after every 10mins and don't want to flush the in-memory database(to support faster queries). Is there a way I can copy from the in-memory database from where I left of earlier and append to the file on disk periodically.

Comment: The [session](https://www.sqlite.org/sessionintro.html) extension sounds like it might be useful for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving to disk an in-memory database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437327/saving-to-disk-an-in-memory-database)