# In-Memory DB to Bytes

Tags: sql, c, database, sqlite

I've an existing sqlite3 DB on my disk. Right now I'm opening it and copying it over to a new and empty in-memory db. So far so good.

Now I need to somehow convert this edited in-memory db into a binary file-format, but that should also be in memory.

I've seen [similar tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437327/saving-to-disk-an-in-memory-database) on how to safe an in-memory db to disk, pretty much the same thing but the converted bytes should just be written into memory, not the disk.

So my `sqlite3* memorydb` should be converted into a byte array.
I took a look at the `struct sqlite3` from the [source code](https://climateequityreference.org/files/doxygen/sqlite3_8c_source.html#l08384), but couldn't find anything I could use for that.

Any ideas on how I could achieve that?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/serialize.html

Comment: @Shawn thank you, exactly what I was looking for!